# Expected Magnitude of Sum of Unit Vectors

Tags: integration, vectors

> a.) What is the expected magnitude of the sum of two unit vectors in the Cartesian plane if the directions of both vectors are randomly chosen from the interval $[−\pi, \pi]$?
>
> A.) $\dfrac43$
> B.) $\sqrt2$
> C.) $\dfrac4\pi$
> D.) $\dfrac9{2\pi}$

This kind of problem involve the same idea of setting up an integral form of expected value, which would be the integral of $xf(x)$ from $[x_1,x_2]$, only I don't know what $f(x)$ would be. I'm not sure if this is the right mindset to use, but any help would greatly be appreciated! :)

Edit: Got rid of second problem due to divergence issues with the expected integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: For a), observe that the problem is unchanged if one of the unit vectors is fixed as $(1, 0)$. Now, can you think of a single parameter $\theta$ to describe the other random unit vector, and describe the magnitude of the sum of the vectors in terms of $\theta$?

[image]

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a sketch of your solution?

Comment: I've added a diagram.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I really appreciate all of the help and have approved your answer, but would it be possible to provide a sketch of the solution. I am bad with vector geometry and cannot figure these problems out for my life

Comment: The magnitude of the sum of the vectors is the magnitude of $u+v$ shown. Can you express the vector $u+v$ in coordinates, in terms of $\theta$?

Comment: Hmm from that, I got 4/pi as the expected value for the first problem and 4rad3/3 for the second. But, one of my friends said the second problem had an expected value of 10rad3/3?

Comment: I haven't fully worked out the second - but your solution is one of the given options so it looks promising!

Comment: If you'd like you can post your working and I can check it?

Comment: I get 2 for the second question actually. The first one is indeed 4/pi, but after setting up a double integral for the second problem, I got 2.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739367/expect-sum-of-magnitudes-of-two-vectors-edited